# Error occurred when I insert a generic data into generic class

Tags: java, arrays, generic-programming

```
public class ArrayList<T> {
    private int noOfElements;
    private T[] data;
    private int lenght;
    public ArrayList()
    {
        lenght = 10;
        data = (T[]) new Object[lenght];
        noOfElements =0;
    }

    public void insert(T value)
    {
        if(noOfElements >= lenght)
        {
            lenght *= 2;
            T temp[] = (T[]) new Object[lenght];
            for(int i = 0;i<noOfElements;i++)
                temp[i] = data[i];
            data = temp;
        }
        data[noOfElements] = value;
        noOfElements++;
    }
}
```

Recently I made a generic class. When I insert data in this class. an error occurred in the insert function the error is shown below:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: PersonInfo

> at ArrayList.insert(ArrayList.java from InputFileObject:26) at
> Driver.main(Driver.java from InputFileObject:9)

anyone can help me?

Comment: Duplicate?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java

Comment: I cna't reproduce. Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: You need to show your Driver class too.

Comment: A question to consider: why do you think `java.util.ArrayList` uses an [`Object[]`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l127) internally, rather than an `E[]`?